# Understanding kafka interbroker communincation

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos

I am using Kafka and have enabled kerberos (SASL_PLAINTEXT using GSSAPI) for kerberos authentication. I am trying to understand on how kerberos work for inter broker authentication here as I dont see any information on jaas config for client side of things here.

server.properties:

```
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT 
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=GSSAPI 
sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://host1:9092
```

jaas config file used.

```
KafkaServer {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=true
    storeKey=true
    keyTab="/local/kafka/config/kafka_server.keytab"
    principal="kafka/host1@Example.com";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Each broker is a client to each other broker when we talk about the inter.broker.protocol, the jaas config you reference is the jaas client configs the brokers will use to communicate. What else are you trying to figure out?

Comment: I found following "KafkaServer is the section name in the JAAS file used by each KafkaServer/Broker. This section provides SASL configuration options for the broker including any SASL client connections made by the broker for inter-broker communication." at https://kafka.apache.org/0110/documentation.html . So with this seems like broker uses this part of JAAS config as a jaas client for inter broker communication as well.